# Does uncopying an information requires a copy of the same program in this scheme? If so, how?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, information, computer

In the paper *Information is Physical* by Rolf Landauer ([reference](http://Physics%20Today%2044,%205,%2023%20(1991);%20doi:%2010.1063/1.881299)), it is claimed that

> Uncopying is not equivalent to erasure and, just like copying, can be done with a dissipation per step proportional to speed. When we reverse a computer after completion of a program and return to the initial state, uncopying can be used to clear out the initial program with minimal dissipation, **if a second copy of that program is available**.

(emphasis is mine)

[image: Figure 5]

However, in Figure 5c, when the potential-well on the left returns to its monostable state, regardless of whether the particles are coupled or not, the particle on the left will end up in the same final state. But this implies that uncopying does not require a copy of the same program.

What am I missing in here?

Edit:
My question is why do we need a copy of the state if uncopying, i.e running the program in the reverse order, is just another program execution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the left potential well does not return to its initial state spontaneusly. To return it back to monostable state, you need to somehow modify it which is done with the second copy of the program but executed in reverse order.

Think about a quantum bit in state $|1\rangle$ which was prepared by quantum NOT gate from qubit in state $|0\rangle$. The qubit remains in theory in state $|1\rangle$ infinitely long (assuming it is perfectly shielded and does not interact with surrounding environment). To get it back to initial state $|0\rangle$ you need to do something. One way is application of the program in reverse order, in this case NOT again.

Of course, you can *reset* the qubit (or your potential well) without having the copy of program, however, this requires energy. But if you *uncopy* the state, you can do so without any energy disipation (assuming the action is extremelly slow) as this is another program execution and not the deletion.

Comment: Thanks for the response but you missed my point: yes we can *uncopy* the state without energy dissipation but the author argues that this is possible only when there is a copy of the state. My question is why do we need a copy of the state if *uncopying*, i.e running the program in the reverse order, is just another program execution.

Comment: @Our:But in the quotation is *a copy of the programme* not the state. This means you have to know what to reverse. I would expect that this is natural but maybe there are some concepts where the programme is forgotten after execution.